# Marshal calls to Qt main thread

Tags: c++, qt, events

I'm wrapping libcommuni, which uses Qt, in a different DLL project, which doesn’t use Qt. As far as I’ve been able to tell, I need to run the Qt message pump (via `QCoreApplication`) to make sure networking, signals, etc. work properly. However, I’m running in to some problems figuring out how to do just that.

Basically, I want to spin up a thread in the DLL, which calls `QCoreApplication::exec()` and pumps all the Qt events. I then want to marshal external calls to the DLL, which are on a different thread, to the Qt main thread, so I can safely use libcommuni.

It looks like the recommended approach is to use signals and slots for this, but I’ve been unable to get that to work. I create a signal on the `QObject` class that is called via the DLL and I connect it to a slot on the `QThread` that runs the Qt message pump. However, if I specify `Qt::QueuedConnection` when connecting the signal and slot, the message is never delivered when I emit the signal. If I omit `Qt::QueuedConnection` altogether, the slot is called immediately on the calling thread rather than the Qt main thread.

I’ve also tried explicitly calling `QCoreApplication::postEvent()` on the DLL thread to send an event to the Qt main thread, but `event(QEvent)` is never called in the target `QThread`.

Any ideas on what I’m doing wrong here? I'm guessing I'm not quite understanding Qt's threading model.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `QObject::connect` without specifying connection type - it uses `Qt::AutoConnection`, which turns into `Qt::DirectConnection` if the signal and slot are in a single thread, or into `Qt::QueuedConnection`, if they are in different threads. So, in your case, I can say, that for the moment, when you connect your signal with your slot, the objects, they belong to, are located in one thread.

In order to make `Qt::QueuedConnection` work, you need an event loop in a thread, which contains slot.

There are two main ways of using QThread:

1. You can derive `QThread` and rewrite `QThread::run`. In that case you should do several things:

   - When creating your thread's object, do not specify parent; remove this object manually.
   - In your thread's constructor call `moveToThread(this)`.
   - In your thread's `run` method call exec after all initialization, but before all removal; thread will leave `exec` right after you call `QThread::quit`.
2. You can derive `QObject`, create `QThread` object, and call `QThread::moveToThread` on your object (which, by the way, should be created without specifying parent) before calling `QThread::start`.

In your case I would recommend using the second method.

That is about threads, but I am not quite sure, your problem isn't connected with `QCoreApplication::exec`.